# What is the name of the quest (Skyrim)?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Once I took this screenshot in Skyrim, but since then I forgot the name of the quest depicted. Could someone remember it, as for me it will take an eternity to go through every quest's plot?

[image]

Comment: Where'd you get the screenshot from?  Wouldn't that have the quest name?

Comment: It's mine. I made it years ago. Just forgot the name and details of the quest.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This screenshot is from the quest [Waking Nightmare](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Waking_Nightmare), right at the end, when Erandur is trying to destroy the [Skull of Corruption](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skull_of_Corruption).

Comment: I've played this game waaaay too much...